# Integration by substitution or by parts

Tags: integration

Could someone explain me how I integrate: $x^3(1+x^2)^{-5/2}$ with the following substitutions:

- $p = 1+x^2$
- $x = \tan t$
- $x = \sinh v$

And if there is any other substitution (or integration by parts) that works faster than these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the way I'd do it:

Writing $x^3=x(1+x^2)-x$, we find that
$$
\frac{x^3}{(1+x^2)^{5/2}}=\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}-\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^{5/2}}
$$
and hence we get one primitive (by inspection),
$$
\int\frac{x^3}{(1+x^2)^{5/2}}\,dx=-\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{1/2}}+\frac{1}{3(1+x^2)^{3/2}}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for selecting my answer. However, only 30 minutes has passed since asking the question, and it might be a good idea to wait a bit longer the next time. Maybe you'll get better answers...

Comment: OK, thank you for the answer and the comment

Answer (score 0):

This was posted some time ago but deleted for no reason. Anyway here's the repost. Let $u=\sqrt{1+x^2}$. Then $\displaystyle du=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ and 
\begin{eqnarray}
\int x^3(1+x^2)^{-\frac{5}{2}}dx&=\int\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}du\\
&=\int\frac{u^2-1}{u^4}du\\
&=-u^{-1}+\frac{u^{-3}}{3}+C\\
&=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}+\frac{1}{3(1+x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}+C
\end{eqnarray}